# Run prolog from command prompt,get input from file and send output to a file

Tags: prolog, command-line-tool

I want to run swipl prolog through command prompt,I want to read input.txt as a query file and want to output result to output.txt

My command line command:

```
swipl -f asd.pl < input.txt > output.txt
```

But my output result is comming on command prompt and getting blank output.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working right for me. Are you sure you are not receiving errors on command prompt ?
Note: to output *stderr* you should use `2>` *filename*

Example (test.pl):

```
:- initialization(main).

main:-
  repeat,
    read(Term),
     writeln(term(Term)),
    Term=end_of_file -> halt, fail.


swipl.exe -f test.pl < test.pl > test.txt  2> stderr.txt
```

writes on test.txt:

```
term((:-initialization main))
term((main:-repeat,read(_G747),writeln(term(_G747)),_G747=end_of_file->halt,fail))
term(end_of_file)
```

and on stderr.txt:

```
% c:/swi/workspace/test.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 4 clauses
```

Comment: i appreciate ur answer,but i am getting welcome message too like "Welcome to prolog  nad its version and at end getting % halt ".how to remove the welcome message and % halt from the end.i am getting whole thing at stderr.txt and nothing at test.txt.Will u tell me which prolog version are using for compiling.

Comment: @Himesh: I am using SWI version 6.2.2, under Windows. To remove the welcome message use `-q` modifier: `swipl.exe -q -f test.pl < test.pl > test.txt  2> stderr.txt`